# React Google Maps unique key error in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this react-google-maps component it is working and I receive all the data from the different locations but the console gives me this error message:

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

In my component, I've added a unique key tho.. what's the problem?

I import the map component on the page simply like that `<Map />`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, Marker, withGoogleMap, withScriptjs, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const Map = () => {

    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
{
    allContentfulHotels {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        location {
          lat
          lon
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)

    const {
        allContentfulHotels: { nodes: locations },
    } = data

    return (
        <>
            {locations.map(({ location }) => {
                console.log(location);
                return (
                    <GoogleMap
                        key={location.id}
                        defaultZoom={15}
                        defaultCenter={{
                            lat: location.lat,
                            lng: location.lon,
                        }}
                    >

                        <Marker
                            key={location.id}
                            position={{
                                lat: location.lat,
                                lng: location.lon,
                            }}
                        >
                        </Marker>

                    </GoogleMap>
                )
            })}
        </>
    )
}

const MapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

const MyMap = () => (
    <div>
        <div
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
        >
            <MapComponent
                isMarkerShown
                loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px` }} />}
                mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
)



export default MyMap
```

Hope someone knows what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're specifying the same key for `<GoogleMap />` and `<Marker />` component, try setting different keys for components:

```
<GoogleMap
  key={`map-${location.id}`}
  defaultZoom={15}
  defaultCenter={{
    lat: location.lat,
    lng: location.lon,
  }}
>
  <Marker
     key={`marker-${location.id}`}
     position={{
       lat: location.lat,
       lng: location.lon,
     }}
  >
  </Marker>
</GoogleMap>
```

Comment: Getting this error now: Encountered two children with the same key, `map-undefined`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: I would like the default center to be the position of the marker, so I kinda use the same ID's twice

Comment: actually, can I even use multiply locations for the default center?

Comment: I want to achieve that the default center is the same as the Marker

Comment: It means that `location.id` is undefined. And as for the other questions, I can't help you with that as the initial question was about React and not `react-google-maps` library.

Answer (score 0):

For Example: I am Using map function as below and set unique key..

```
{locations.map(({ location }, index) => {
            console.log(location);  
            console.log(index);
            return (
                <GoogleMap
                    key={index}
                    defaultZoom={15}
                    defaultCenter={{
                        lat: location.lat,
                        lng: location.lon,
                    }}
```